# Open project in Android Studio 1.0+ using gradle plugin 0.*.*

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to open a Android Project in Android Studio 1.0.2 which uses

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
```

as its dependency. On opening the project with above dependency I get the following error message.

```
The project is using an unsupported version of the Android Gradle plug-in (0.12.2). The recommended version is 1.0.0.
```

Is there a way to run such projects in Android Studio 1.0.+ without upgrading the Gradle plug-in version

Note:

I can upgrade the gradle version and plugin to get it to work OR simply use older version of Android Studio to open the project.

First approach is not desirable since this being a community project I will prefer to leave majority of files unchanged and changing gradle version will also hinder me from testing the build with 0.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To successfully build Android project using Android Studion and Gradle you need to use the AS, Gradle and Android Gradle Plugin with versions which are compatible with each other. Check out [this page](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility), it's said here, that you can use Android Gradle Plugin 0.12 with Android Studio 0.8.0 - 0.8.11 and there is no way to use it under Android Studio 1.0.
I suggest you convince other people to switch to the newest version of Android Gradle Plugin because 1.0.0 is the stable one and doesn't contain some bugs which were out there in the 0.12.+.

Comment: It seems that I will have to maintain multiple versions of Android. Couple of weeks ago when I visited that site. That page wasn't there. Thanks for the link.